# Adobe Air drops Events silently?

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

In my Adobe Air application I have a change event handler attached to a mx:DataGrid. When I'm debugging the application in FlashBuilder 4 the handler is executed, everything works fine. But as soon as I install the application the handler stops being executed!

I've added plenty of logging to the application, no errors are thrown. It's just the change event handler that's somehow not working anymore… everything else works (buttons, switching states, fetching remote data,…)

When I start a fresh project to test if I can reproduce the error the change event handler is being executed correctly!! Any ideas on errors that don't are silently ignored that could cause those symptoms?

I'm working with FlexORM, SQLite, FlashBuilder 4 beta 2 and Flex 4 SDK b 10485.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the error lies within my usage of SQLite and FlexORM.

FlexORM somehow creates different databases when run from within FlashBuilder. Due to those differences some queries fail, which causes the app to freeze but the AIR runtime tries to keep it running…

Odd indeed! But at least I now know how to fix it :-)

Comment: Eventually the FlashBuilder is removing custom metadata tags on release build/ export which causes FlexORM to create a different table structure in the first place...

Comment: And eventually the -keep-as3-metadata option was removed in flex 3.3 and beyond… adobe, WHY? :-(

Comment: Apparently
 "-keep-as3-metadata+=Table,Id,Column,ManyToOne,OneToMany,ManyToMany,Transient"
works just fine with Flex 4 beta even tho the compiler option is no longer listed as supported. Fixed! :)